# Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'UInt8'

Tags: objective-c, swift

Translating Obj-C to Swift. As you can see I declared `let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef))` so I'm getting the error in the for loop below it.

> Binary operator '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'Int' and 'UInt8'

Also as a little addendum I don't know how to translate the remaining Obj-C code below the for loop. What does that slash mean and how do I deal with the pointer? I have to say UnsafeMutableFloat somewhere?

```swift
 // process the frame of video
    func captureOutput(captureOutput:AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer, fromConnection connection:AVCaptureConnection) {
        // if we're paused don't do anything
        if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
            // reset our frame counter
            self.validFrameCounter = 0

            return
        }

    // this is the image buffer
    var cvimgRef:CVImageBufferRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvimgRef, 0)
    // access the data
    var width: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvimgRef)
    var height:size_t = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvimgRef)
    // get the raw image bytes
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef))
    var bprow: size_t = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvimgRef)


    var r = 0
    var g = 0
    var b = 0

        for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
            for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {
                b += buf[x]; g += buf[x + 1]; r += buf[x + 2] // error
            }
            buf += bprow() // error
        }
```

Remaining Obj-C code.

```
r/=255*(float) (width*height);
g/=255*(float) (width*height);
b/=255*(float) (width*height);
```

Comment: the slash stands for division...

Comment: Read the error message and have a look at your variables! `var r = 0` defines an `Int`, and `buf[x]` is an `UInt8`. Then read the Swift book: *"Values are never implicitly converted to another type"* ... And the stars in `r/=255*(float) (width*height);` do *not* indicate pointers :)

Comment: ok I will read it Martin. But regarding the division sign Volker. I obviously thought it was that but then I thought it was just something else because how can you have a division sign before an assignment operator? So then Martin this statement means `var r /= 255 * (width*height)`? I thought the first asterisk was a pointer. Oops. Do I put commas after each one of these assignments or semi-colons? Oh, Swift doesn't need anything?

Comment: Of course I have trouble with both. I state that I am a new programmer in almost most of my posts. I started programming about 2 months ago. Just finished course tracks at TeamTreeHouse and just enrolled in a CS course at my uni. Thanks for helping me out. Studying both at the same time so my brain is toast these days.

Comment: @Edward `/=` is called a compound assignment operator and is also covered in the Swift documentation (along with documentation for all of the C-based languages...).  There are *several* different compound operators.  `/=` is *no* different from `+=` except that it does division rather than addition.

Comment: nhgrif. I am aware of all of the operators. Thank you for explaining to me. As my post above states I didn't think it was an operator at first because of the syntax of the rest of the statement. It just threw me off. Sometimes when I don't see let / var it confuses me. Same as how I thought the multiplication was a pointer :) I'm knee deep in all the Swift docs all day.

Comment: If I saw `let` or `var` in Objective-C code, I'd be extraordinarily confused.

Comment: Yes but I am new to programming and translating all day so I think it's easy to see how someone like me can not see many things for what they are.

Comment: So Martin I read page 4/5. Nothing I didn't already know from course 101. However, being  a noob with only weeks of programming exposure, grasping the concept and knowing the syntax are often unrelated. It's better to get the answer and see how the syntax and logic relate together and move on to the next problem rather than play scrabble with Swift names. I tried doublevalue, UInt8, Int etc no go.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a lot of type mismatch error.

The type of `x` should not be `UInt8` because `x` to increase until the value of the width.

```
for var x:UInt8 = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {  // error: '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt8' and 'Int'
```

So fix it like below:

```
for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {
```

To increment the pointer address, you can use `advancedBy()` function.

```
buf += bprow(UnsafeMutablePointer(UInt8))  // error: '+=' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>' and 'size_t'
```

Like below:

```
var pixel = buf.advancedBy(y * bprow)
```

And this line,

```
RGBtoHSV(r, g, b)  // error
```

There are no implicit casts in Swift between `CGFloat` and `Float` unfortunately. So you should cast explicitly to `CGFloat`.

```
RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), g: CGFloat(g), b: CGFloat(b))
```

The whole edited code is here:

```
func RGBtoHSV(r: CGFloat, g: CGFloat, b: CGFloat) -> (h: CGFloat, s: CGFloat, v: CGFloat) {
    var h: CGFloat = 0.0
    var s: CGFloat = 0.0
    var v: CGFloat = 0.0
    let col = UIColor(red: r, green: g, blue: b, alpha: 1.0)
    col.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &v, alpha: nil)
    return (h, s, v)
}

// process the frame of video
func captureOutput(captureOutput:AVCaptureOutput, didOutputSampleBuffer sampleBuffer:CMSampleBuffer, fromConnection connection:AVCaptureConnection) {
    // if we're paused don't do anything
    if currentState == CurrentState.statePaused {
        // reset our frame counter
        self.validFrameCounter = 0
        return
    }

    // this is the image buffer
    var cvimgRef = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer)
    // Lock the image buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(cvimgRef, 0)
    // access the data
    var width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(cvimgRef)
    var height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(cvimgRef)
    // get the raw image bytes
    let buf = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>(CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(cvimgRef))
    var bprow = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRow(cvimgRef)

    var r: Float = 0.0
    var g: Float = 0.0
    var b: Float = 0.0

    for var y = 0; y < height; y++ {
        var pixel = buf.advancedBy(y * bprow)
        for var x = 0; x < width * 4; x += 4 {  // error: '<' cannot be applied to operands of type 'UInt8' and 'Int'
            b += Float(pixel[x])
            g += Float(pixel[x + 1])
            r += Float(pixel[x + 2])
        }
    }
    r /= 255 * Float(width * height)
    g /= 255 * Float(width * height)
    b /= 255 * Float(width * height)

    //}

    // convert from rgb to hsv colourspace
    var h: Float = 0.0
    var s: Float = 0.0
    var v: Float = 0.0

    RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), g: CGFloat(g), b: CGFloat(b))  // error
}
```

Comment: Insane. Thank you so much. I had to change your function call to this `RGBtoHSV(CGFloat(r), CGFloat(g), CGFloat(b))` because I was getting an Xcode Fixit error.